# Error: website is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I am deploying a .netCore API to the IIS server with SQL DB.

I used a script to generate the DB from my device to the server.
I Publish my app with the connection string :

```
 "DefaultConnection": "Data source=<myServer>;Initial Catalog=<MyDatabaseName>;Integrated Security=True"
```

it deployed and showing the swagger UI but any request is not working
I think my issue is caused by Connection String, but I don't know how to fix
and I have a question about how should I handle migration in the deploying phase?

Comment: When `Integrated Security=True` is used, you need to set a valid application pool identity on IIS to connect to database. Ask your database administrators to assist as they often know what to do next.

Comment: @LexLi  thank you for replying, I am just trying to deploy as a test. what is the standard connection string for deploying an app ? should I create a new login to my DB and add it to the connection string?

Comment: About how to configure sal db connection string you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-3-configure-data-source-settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-3-configure-data-source-settings) and [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561653/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561653/13336642).

Comment: @samwu thank you so much, I enabled the sa login account for my SQL and added it to my connection string and it works!
so  my connection string looks like that: 
`code`
    "DefaultConnection": 
"Data source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=sa;Password=myPassword;"
`code`